# How to compare two rows (selected by defined conditions) across all column?

Tags: r, select, compare, row

I have a data frame with many columns and rows, for example

```
ID  Group A B   C   D   E   F   G   … 
1   1   0.1 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.9 0.0 0.0 …
2   1   0.1 0.0 0.0 0.7 0.0 0.0 0.3 …
3   2   0.0 0.1 0.6 0.0 0.0 0.2 0.0 …
1   1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 …
3   1   0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.6 0.0 …
1   2   0.2 0.1 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 …
2   2   0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 …
1   2   0.0 0.2 0.8 0.0 0.0 1.3 1.1 …
```

I'd like to compare the rows with same ID across all column from A to the end. In the compared rows, if there is at least one value from group 1 is not zero, and there is at least one value from group 2 is not zero, then write this column name and value into a table. So the output table would look like this:

```
ID  Group A B   C   D   E   F   G   … 
1   1   0.1 NA  0.5 NA  NA  NA  NA  … 
1   1   0.0 NA  0.0 NA  NA  NA  NA  … 
1   2   0.2 NA  0.2 NA  NA  NA  NA  … 
1   2   0.0 NA  0.8 NA  NA  NA  NA  … 
2   1   0.1 NA  NA  0.7 NA  NA  0.3 … 
2   2   0.1 NA  NA  0.1 NA  NA  0.1 … 
3   2   NA  0.1 NA  NA  NA  0.2 NA  … 
3   1   NA  0.5 NA  NA  NA  0.6 NA  …
```

As I am new to use R, this seems to be a big challenge for me. I would appreciate any help on my question. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you very much editing my question. Now it looks professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option using `dplyr`, it's used your logic but in the opposite way I hope it solves your problem. For a given column, we replace column values for a given ID with NA when all values in group 1 or 2 are equal to zero.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(ID) %>%   # arrange ID in ascending order
       group_by(ID) %>%  # group by ID
       #mutate at all columns except ID and Group
       mutate_at(vars(-ID,-Group), ~replace(.,all(.[Group==1]==0)|all(.[Group==2]==0),NA)) 

# A tibble: 8 x 9
# Groups:   ID [3]
      ID Group    A     B     C     D     E     F     G
     <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
  1     1     1   0.1  NA     0.5  NA      NA  NA    NA  
  2     1     1   0    NA     0    NA      NA  NA    NA  
  3     1     2   0.2  NA     0.2  NA      NA  NA    NA  
  4     1     2   0    NA     0.8  NA      NA  NA    NA  
  5     2     1   0.1  NA    NA     0.7    NA  NA     0.3
  6     2     2   0.1  NA    NA     0.1    NA  NA     0.1
  7     3     2  NA     0.1  NA    NA      NA   0.2  NA  
  8     3     1  NA     0.5  NA    NA      NA   0.6  NA
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text ="
ID  Group A B   C   D   E   F   G    
1   1   0.1 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.9 0.0 0.0 
                 2   1   0.1 0.0 0.0 0.7 0.0 0.0 0.3 
                 3   2   0.0 0.1 0.6 0.0 0.0 0.2 0.0 
                 1   1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
                 3   1   0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.6 0.0 
                 1   2   0.2 0.1 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 
                 2   2   0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 
                 1   2   0.0 0.2 0.8 0.0 0.0 1.3 1.1",
                           header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```